# Angularjs Kendo Master-detail grid Apply Default ID from Master to Add New Detail Record

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am trying to get the value from the ID field on the expanded row from the Master grid in order to populate the corresponding field on the Details grid when adding a new record in the Details grid.  I tried the following:

```
$scope.detailGridOptions = function (dataItem) {
  return {
      dataSource: {
          type: 'aspnetmvc-ajax',
          transport: {
              read: "/Home/GetTaggedContractorsByMajor"
              ,
              create: "/Home/AddContractorToTag"
          },
          serverPaging: true,
          serverSorting: true,
          serverFiltering: true,
          schema: {
              data: "Data",
              total: "Total",
              model: {
                id: "ContractorID",
                fields: {
                    CompanyID: { editable: true, nullable: true, type: "string" },
                    TagID: { editable: true, nullable: true, type: "number" },
                    vchCompanyName: { editable: false, nullable: false, type: "string"},
                    Date: { editable: false, nullable: false, type: "date" },
                    AddedBy: { editable: false, nullable: false, type: "string" }
          }
      }
          },
          pageSize: 5,
          filter: { field: "TagID", operator: "eq", value: dataItem.TagID }
      },
      scrollable: false,
      sortable: true,
      pageable: true,
      editable: "popup",
      edit: function (e) {
              var uid = $(this.element[0]).closest('.k-detail-row').prev().attr('data-uid');
          var selector = kendo.format("tr[data-uid='{0}']", uid);
          var currentGridElement = $(selector).closest("[data-role=grid]");
          var parentRow = currentGridElement.closest(".k-detail-row").prev();
          var parentGrid = parentRow.closest("[data-role=grid]").data("kendoGrid");
          var parentModel = parentGrid.dataItem(parentRow);
          return {
              TagID: parentModel.TagID
          };
      },
      toolbar: ["create"],
      columns: [
      {
          field: "TagID"
        , hidden: true
      }
      ,
          {
              field: "CompanyID",
              title: "CompanyID"
              , editor: companyDropDownEditor
          }
      ,
        {
            field: "vchCompanyName",
            title: "Company Name"
        }
        ,
          {
              field: "Date",
              title: "Date Added"
          }
          ,
          {
              field: "AddedBy",
              title: "Added By"
          }
      ]

  };
```

};

"parentGrid" variable is always null.  However, if use the name of the grid directily as `$scope.tagsGrid`, I can get the grid but the line `var parentModel = $scope.tagsGrid.dataItem(parentRow);` gives the error "Unable to get property 'TagID' of undefined or null reference".  I think even if I am able to get that part of the code working, I am still missing something as trying to manually set the ID like this

```
          return {
              TagID: 1
          };
```

does not set the ID either.  If it is not possible to automatically set the ID field for the new detail row, is it possible to get the ID value from Master and send it as a parameter with my create Url?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked whether `parentRow` is actually non-`null`?

Comment: Hi, yes, thank you.  parentRow was not null, but I don't think it had the right information.  As I believe the initial uid was incorrect.  Was able to accomplish what I was attempting to do.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help anymore! I've worked with kendo before, but I currently don't have access to it

Comment: No.  Thank you very much.  I appreciate the time you took to try to help.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work with a few tweaks to the edit event function:

```
edit: function (e) {
          var grid = $scope.tagsGrid;
          var uid = e.model.uid;
          var selector = kendo.format("tr[data-uid='{0}']", uid);
          var currentGridElement = $(selector).closest("[data-role=grid]");
          var parentRow = currentGridElement.closest(".k-detail-row").prev();
          var parentModel = grid.dataItem(parentRow);
          e.model.TagID = parentModel.TagID;
      },
```